# How to add and divide php values

Tags: php

I'm building a grading system and I want "+" and "/"

like this :

for example: c71st="89" c72nd="90" c73rd="89" c74th="70"

```
<?php echo $userinfo['c71st'] ?> + <?php echo $userinfo['c71st'] ?> + <?php 
echo $userinfo['c71st'] ?> + <?php echo $userinfo['c71st'] ?> /2
```

how can I add and divide this ? 
when I type + it only display + sign in php form or html

this is different from other questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

just add and divide them on php. not in html or javascript

```
<?php echo ($userinfo['c71st'] + $userinfo['c71st'] + $userinfo['c71st'])/2; ?>
```

Comment: how can i do this inside of php ? like this    echo "<td><select name='c71stgfilipino[$i]' class='form-control'>
     <option>{$userinfo['c71stgfilipino']}+{$userinfo['c72ndgfilipino']}</option>

Comment: you don't need to echo an element because you can just create an html element with a php script in a php file

Answer (score 0):

First You have to create $userinfo array

```
<?php
    $userinfo = array("c71st"=> 89, "c72nd"=> 90, "c73rd"=> 89, "c74th"=> 70);
    echo ($userinfo['c71st'] + $userinfo['c71st'] + $userinfo['c71st'] + $userinfo['c71st']) / 2 ;
    ?>
```

Comment: will try this :) wait

Comment: how can i do this inside of php ? like this echo "<td><select name='c71stgfilipino[$i]' class='form-control'> <option>{$userinfo['c71stgfilipino']}+{$userinfo['c72nd‌​gfilipino']}</option‌​>

Comment: What to want to create, please elaborate your query with your code . ?

Comment: I want do to that inside of php with select inside

Comment: Show me your html code where you implement your php